# Using a variable to access an array index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, indexing

I'm trying to use a variable to access an array value but I get an undefined error.

```
var ordernum = 54;
keys[ordernum][ "keys" ];

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined
```

If I do `keys["54"][ "keys" ];` it works just fine. However, I need to use the variable as this code is in a `for` loop.

How can I use the variable to get the same outcome?

Full code:

```
    var customers = <?php if ( isset($customers) ) { echo json_encode($customers); } ?>;
    var keys = <?php if ( isset($keystable) ) { echo json_encode($keystable); } ?>;

for ( var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++ ) {
            var ordernum = customers[ i ][ "order" ];
            table += '<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">';
            table += '<td>' + customers[ i ][ "email" ] + '</td>';
            table += '<td>' + customers[ i ][ "org" ] + '</td>';
            table += '<td style="width:450px;">' + customers[ i ][ "notes" ] + '</td>';
            table += '<td>' + keys[ordernum.toString()][ "keys" ] + '</td>';
            table += '</tr>';
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the full code in question?

Comment: I have done @CertainPerformance

Comment: That doesn't show what the `customers` or `keys` array actually is though, which is integral to the question - can you post the full rendered HTML, not the unknown echoed variables?

Comment: Create an minimal reproducible able example. What is the content of `customers` and  `keys`? Don't show the `<?php if ( isset($customers) ) { echo json_encode($customers); } ?>` but the actual object that is place there after php is evaluate, the code you see in the source of the browser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If keys["54"]["keys"] is working, that means first key is a string. Then you need to make the variable a string.

```
var ordernum = "54";
keys[ordernum][ "keys" ];
```

or

```
var ordernum = 54;
keys[ordernum.toString()][ "keys" ];
```

Comment: I don't know any js interpreter that wouldn't do that automatically. [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jzm3rdu6/)

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong and shouldn't have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would work for you:

```
var ordernum = 54;
keys[ordernum+""][ "keys" ];
```

Comment: I don't know any js interpreter that wouldn't do that automatically. [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jzm3rdu6/)

Comment: @t.niese, that's the reason that i used "Probably". according to what explained in the question, it seems that the problem is because `54` is not string.

Answer (score -1):

What you are saying is impossible (well, not **technically** impossible but it would require some js magic based on proxies that I'm pretty sure is not present in your case).

Probably your keys is not `"54"` but `" 54"`, `"054"` or something similar.

Check out what the keys are really with something like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(keys)));
```

Another very frequent mistake is that you are using asynchronous data collection (AJAX) and your loop runs too early (you need to put your processing in the callback and you're instead running it right after making the AJAX call).